# Otree: how to access participant.id_in_session

Tags: python, database, otree

I am trying to access the variable 'id_in_session', which I see in the data export

[image]

but when I refer to it as I would to normal participant variables

```
 player.participant.vars['id_in_session']
```

it does not work. Is it possible to work with these automatically created participant variables like 'id_in_session'?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was to use

```
player.participant.vars['id_in_session']
```

instead of

```
player.participant.id_in_session
```

Apparently, this variables is not stored in the vars.